# Why am I receiving an error in CLI when inputting this command?

Tags: command-line-interface

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($URL, $OUTPUT_FILE)
```

That command above is simply a copy-paste that I'm instructed to `input into CLI`.  This is the error it returns:

> "Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s):  "An exception
> occurred during a WebClient request."

The exam only calls for me to input a number of preset commands, but it won't take the above command to continue.  This is for Coursera.  Any ideas?

As for what I tried, I don't know enough to try anything other than seeking troubleshooting advice because Coursera has seemingly terrible student support for specific labs.

Comment: Probably dumb question but given your newness to code...are you simply calling `(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($URL, $OUTPUT_FILE)`?

Comment: It's just a series of commands that I'm supposed to copy/paste into CLI, like a hands-on practice.  The exercise is asking for me to download and install VLC through PowerShell.  Every previous commands to the one above work fine.  The one above returns, "Exception calling 'DownloadFile' with '2' argument(s):  "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

I'm so new, I can't figure it out, and Coursera has regrettable lab support.